# Minimize $\max (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) + \min (x_2, y_2) + z_1 + z_2$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

Minimize $\max (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) + \min (x_2, y_2) + z_1 + z_2$ where $x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+z_1+z_2=1$ and $0 \leq x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2 \leq 1$

The only thing I can think to do is the standard multivariable calculus technique of looking for critical points and then optimizing over the boundary of this 5-dimensional domain. However, the problem "looks" so simple that I suspect there is an easier/more elegant way.

I've read about linear programming but only for linear objective functions, and this one is piecewise linear.

Comment: Can you solve a simpler problem?  What if it were $\max(x_1, y_1) + \min(x_2, y_2)$?  If that's too hard, what if it were $\max(x_1, y_1)$ or $\min(x_2, y_2)$ or $z_1 + z_2$?

Comment: I would say $x_1=y_1$ since that optimizes the max term. Then I would choose $x_2=0$ because that optimizes the min term and I can make $y_2$ as big as I want. So my solution is $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)=(1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3)$ and the objective function evaluates to $1/3+0=1/3$.

Comment: Should we use slack variables or is that overkill?

Comment: Sorry, I very stupidly missed the condition that the sum must be $1$ when I wrote my answer.  I think you ought to be able to solve this by guessing an initial solution and then seeing what happens to the objective function when you perturb the input values slightly, subject to the constraint.  The components of the objective function are all monotonic, so there shouldn't be any local minima that aren't also global minima, which means that the initial guess doesn't matter and so hill-climbing (the perturbations) ought to get you to the global minimum.

Comment: Agreed, though I'm less interested in the solution than I am in the simplest approach. Perhaps we can assume without loss of generality that x_1=y_1 and x_2=0?

Then the problem becomes minimizing $\max(a,b) + c$ with $a+b+c=1$ and the min is clearly 1/2.

Comment: (1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 0) yields a value of 1/3, so your most recent idea doesn't work.

Comment: @CalvinLin To be clear, is your point in the form $(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2)$? Then yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing out that mistake, I understand now. With the simplifying assumptions I suggested, the new problem is instead $\max(a,b) + c$ with $2a+b+2c=1$ whose min is 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned} \min & \max (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) + \min (x_2, y_2) + z_1 + z_2 \\ & x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+z_1+z_2=1 \\ & 0 \leq x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2 \leq 1\end{aligned}$$ is a bit complicated for an LP. The `min max` part is easy. The `min min` is non-convex and requires a binary variable:

$$\begin{aligned} \min\> & v_1  + v_2 + z_1 + z_2 \\ & v_1 \ge x_1 \\ & v_1 \ge y_1 \\ & v_1 \ge x_2 \\ & v_1 \ge y_2\\ & v_2 \le x_2 \\ & v_2 \le y_2 \\ & v_2 \ge x_2 - \delta \\ & v_2 \ge y_2 - (1-\delta) \\ & x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+z_1+z_2=1 \\ & 0 \leq x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2 \leq 1 \\ & \delta \in \{0,1\} \\ & v_1,v_2 \ge 0 \end{aligned}$$

Here we have in the optimal solution: $v_1 = \max (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ and $v_2 = \min (x_2, y_2)$. With the presence of the binary variable $\delta$ we need a MIP solver (or solve two LPs, one with $\delta=0$ and one with $\delta=1$).

Comment: What if we restrict the feasible region to
$$x_1+y_1+z_1=1/2$$
$$x_2+y_2+z_2=1/2$$
Can we use the same reasoning?

Comment: Yes. You can use different constraints. I have used that all variables are between 0 and 1. Things need to change a bit when that assumption is violated.